# Having trouble aligning image within div

Tags: html, css, vertical-alignment

I've been trying to align two images within the nav bar, but they won't align vertically properly. They appear to be slightly above the intended area. If anyone could offer some help, that would be greatly appreciated

- Richard

http://jsfiddle.net/afxbp/

HTML:

```
<div class="top-bar-wrapper">
<div class="top-bar">
    <ul class="nav-bar-left">
        <li class="logo">
            <img src="resources/logo2.png" height="35px" width="35px">
        </li>
        <li class="title">
            <img src="resources/title.png" height="25px" width="235px">
        </li>
    </ul>
    <ul class="nav-bar-right">
        <li><a href="index.html">Home</a>
        </li>
        <li><a href="">About</a>
        </li>
        <li><a href="">Products</a>
        </li>
        <li><a href="">Login/Register</a>
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.top-bar-wrapper {
margin: auto;
overflow: auto;
box-shadow: 0 0 5px #000;
top: 0;
position:fixed;
left:0;
right:0;
background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, rgb(79, 19, 4), rgb(70, 20, 4));
/*Safari 5.1-6*/
background: -o-linear-gradient(top, rgb(79, 19, 4), rgb(70, 20, 4));
/*Opera 11.1-12*/
background: -moz-linear-gradient(top, rgb(79, 19, 4), rgb(70, 20, 4));
/*Fx 3.6-15*/
background: linear-gradient(top, rgb(79, 19, 4), rgb(70, 20, 4));
/*Standard*/
}
.top-bar {
margin: auto;
overflow: auto;
z-index: 1000;
display:block;
width: 1024px;
background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, rgba(79, 19, 4, 1), rgba(70, 20, 4, 1));
/*Safari 5.1-6*/
background: -o-linear-gradient(top, rgba(79, 19, 4, 1), rgba(70, 20, 4, 1));
/*Opera 11.1-12*/
background: -moz-linear-gradient(top, rgba(79, 19, 4, 1), rgba(70, 20, 4, 1));
/*Fx 3.6-15*/
background: linear-gradient(top, rgba(79, 19, 4, 1), gba(70, 20, 4, 1));
/*Standard*/
}
.top-bar ul {
line-height: 45px;
margin: 0;
padding: 0;
list-style: none;
font-family:'Ubuntu', sans-serif;
}
.top-bar a {
text-decoration: none;
color: #ffffff;
font-size: 14px;
display:block;
}
.nav-bar-left {
float: left;
}
.nav-bar-left li {
text-align: center;
float: left;
display: block;
padding: 0 10px 0 0;
height:45px;
}
.nav-bar-left img {
vertical-align:middle;
}
.nav-bar-right {
float: right;
}
.nav-bar-right li {
text-align: center;
float: left;
width: 115px;
}
.nav-bar-right li:hover {
transition: background 0.4s;
background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, rgba(105, 13, 4, 1), rgba(85, 13, 4, 1));
/*Safari 5.1-6*/
background: -o-linear-gradient(top, rgba(105, 13, 4, 1), rgba(85, 13, 4, 1));
/*Opera 11.1-12*/
background: -moz-linear-gradient(top, rgba(105, 13, 4, 1), rgba(85, 13, 4, 1));
/*Fx 3.6-15*/
background: linear-gradient(top, rgba(105, 13, 4, 1), rgba(85, 13, 4, 1));
/*Standard*/
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this code

```
.nav-bar-left img {
   vertical-align: middle;
   display: inline-block;
   margin-top: -2px;
}
```

Comment: I changed the margin-top to -4px which made it look nicer, but I don't understand why I should need to use the margin property? Why doesn't it align automatically? Cheers

Comment: It happens because `.top-bar ul` has `line-height: 45px`, which also get applied to `img`.